# What to say in letters while mentioning a proprietorship?

Tags: professionalism

Usually, when you work in a company, in official letters (leave application, resignation and such), you mention that you are an employee at this company or your are leaving your position in this company and etc. What to write in place of "your company" or "this company" when it is not a company(not pvt ltd, llp or inc, or such) but a proprietorship?

The place I work in is a studio but it is not registered as a company in my best knowledge, but it is listed as a trademark (the name of the studio is not a company's name, the name is registered as a trademark.) and has a proprietor who is the boss.

Comment: A country or more specific locality might help get you a relevant answer.

Comment: What is the entity paying your paycheck?

Comment: Not sure why this is a question. Just write the name on the door. Or, given that it’s a small, informal organization, don’t write anything at all — just say “bye” and leave.

Answer (score 4):

> What to write in place of "your company" or "this company" when it is not a company(not pvt ltd, llp or inc, or such) but a proprietorship?

Considering all your examples are about writing a letter *to this "company"*, you can just give the "company" name instead and avoid all ambiguity. You're not trying to keep it a secret!

If you want to keep it a secret for whatever reason and you're writing a letter elsewhere, then I'd suggest "place of work" is the most generic, all-encompassing term you can use.